# How are functions executed in a class

Tags: php, class, function

This may be a simples question but i couldn't find the answer..

If i have a class and declare the value of a variable within a function being called from a while statement and then use that variable later in another function when does that variable get changed to the next value in the array?

ie.. I know that php  executes code form top to bottom, but is that true with classes and functions being called from with in another function. Does php wait to go to the next item in the while statement until all functions and sub functions have been called or does it call a function then move to the next item in the list??

```
class myClass{
     public $cust;

     function __construct(){
        $sql = mysql_query("SOME QUERY");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            myClass::sendEmail();
        }
     }

     function sendEmail(){
    $this->cust = new selectDatabase();
    $this->cust->table = "customer_main";
    $this->cust->where = " WHERE customerID = '".$customerID."' ";
    $this->cust->getItems();

    $this->cust->name = $name;
    $this->cust->email = $email;     

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT EmailTo, EmailFrom, EmailSubject, EmailBody
                                FROM system_email");
            $row = mysql_fetch_assc($sql);

            $to = myClass::dbReplace($row['EmailTo']);
            $From = myClass::dbReplace($row['EmailFrom']);
            $subject = myClass::dbReplace($row['EmailSubject']);
            $body = myClass::dbReplace($row['EmailBody']);

    $headers = "From: ".$from." \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $headers .= "Bcc: stoneops@cornell.edu\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers);


     }
private function dbReplace($thisStr){
    $x = substr_count($thisStr,"DB[");
    $z = 0;
        $holdArry = array();
        while($z < $x){
            $rplStr = genEmail::findSubStr($thisStr);
            $t = substr_count($thisStr, "DB[".$rplStr."]");
            $rplStr2 = split(':', $rplStr);
            $thisStr = str_replace("DB[".$rplStr."]", $this->{$rplStr2[0]}->{$rplStr2[1]}, $thisStr);
            $z = $z +$t;
        }
    return $thisStr;
}

private function findSubStr($str){
    $pos = strpos($str, 'DB['); // outputs ER@EXAMPLE.com
    $pt1 = substr($str, ($pos + 3) );
    $pos = strpos($pt1, ']');
    $pt2 = substr($pt1, -1 * strlen(substr($pt1, $pos)));
    $pt2 = str_replace($pt2, "", $pt1);
    return $pt2;
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it? I see no better way of finding out. Also [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).

Answer (score 1):

- Normally, it will execute from top to bottom, one-by-one through a sequence of code.
- If there are functions and methods, the PHP interpreter will mark them, but they won't be executed unless they are called from else where.
- A function or a method once is called, will be executed from top to the `return` statement. When it finishes returning or doing some jobs, the next item will be reached and executed.

Answer (score 1):

Execution is done from in the order they are called, so it's a sequential order. It is synchronous, so yes, PHP will wait until a function and it's sub functions have returned before it moves to the next one. This is referred to as the **[call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)**.

If that wasn't the case, you'd have a lot of [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) on your hand, which would make programming near impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Sequential execution. So it will execute each function/statement in order from top to bottom, waiting for each function/statement to finish before calling the next one, then it will hit the end of the loop and start again at the beginning.